# How can I get the echo output of a php script from a php script on my server?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am working on a backend for my school's website and I have run into a problem. I am powering a blog on the homepage and for teacher websites and have setup an SSO system between the two. I am linking into it for a unified admin panel that I am making to manage them and a dynamic calendar via a php script that is placed inside of the homepage's blog directory. It doesn't work if it is not in the blog's directory My problem is that it echos a JSON array of the current logged in user and I am having trouble getting the json array from the admin panel that I am developing.
**Here is the code of the script in the blog's directory:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
include 'wp-blog-header.php';

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $userInfo = ((array) $current_user);
    $loggedIn = true;
} else {
    $userInfo = null;
    $loggedIn = false;
}

echo json_encode(array(
    'loggedIn' => $loggedIn,
    'userInfo' => $userInfo
));
?>
```

**Here is the code of the current script in the admin panel:**

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
$response = file_get_contents(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/homepage-blog/controlPanelUserCommunicate.php');
var_dump($response);
?>
```

**Here is the output of current script in the admin panel:**

```
string(374) " $loggedIn, 'userInfo' => $userInfo )); ?>"
```

Comment: you acessing the file directly, so you gets contents, its not being run though the web server to process the php

Comment: Then how can I make it run through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you accessing the file directly, so you gets contents, its not being run though the web server to process the php

you probably want

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://SITE/controlPanelUserCommunicate.php');
```